# Velocity of an Object Accelerated by an Inductor

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, kinematics, electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I am currently trying to build a coil gun as a class project (for an introductory programming/electronics class), and I want to be able to determine the launch angle necessary to send an object a particular distance.

I have been able to work out the kinematics just fine given an initial velocity, but I don't have much of a background in electromagnetism, and I'm having trouble determining what that initial velocity would be.

I would have a simple inductor, formed by wrapping a coil of wire around a PVC pipe, connected to a 3.3V power supply (that could be increased if necessary).

Given the circuit specifications, is there any way to find the acceleration delivered by the inductor over a time interval? Or, is there a way I could find the kinetic energy of a projectile leaving an inductor? Is there some relationship between the energy stored in an inductor, $\frac{1}{2}LI^2$, and the kinetic energy it gives to a projectile?

I could measure the initial velocity with a sensor, but I imagine finding it mathematically would be more accurate.

Comment: No, a measurement is almost always more accurate and easier to arrange. There are several factors which affect the speed at which the projectile is ejected from the coil, some of which could be difficult to quantify. You do not even require a sensor for the measurement, you could use the range with horizontal launch. .